# How to take a TSV file and convert to JSON in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a TSV file that has this in its file

```
Row ID  O ID    O Date  Ship Date   Ship Type   Customer ID Customer Name   Seg Country City    State   Zip Code    Region  Product ID  Category    Sub-Category    Product Name    Sales   Quantity    Discount    Profit
1   PA-152156   11/9/20 01/19/16    Second Class    CG-125  Clay bute   Consumer    United States   Henderson   Kentucky    42420   South   FUR-BO-10001798 Furniture   Bookcases   Bush, Somerset Collection Bookcase? 261.96  2   0   41.9136
2   PA-152156   11/18/20    01/19/16    Second Class    CG-120  Clay Bute   Consumer    United States   Henderson   Kentucky    42420   South   FUR-CH-10000454 Furniture   Chairs   Deluxe Fabric Upholstered Stacking Chairs, Rounded Back    731.94  3   0   219.582
```

That is just a sample. Theres a bit 100 lines items. I wanted to read this tsv file and display it as a JSON object in the format:

```
"Customer Name": {
        "orders": [
            {
                "order_id": "CA-1234-567890",
                "order_date": "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS",
                "line_items": [
                    {
                        "product_url": "https://www.fake.com/cat/subcat/123",
                        "business": 123.45
                    },
                    {
                        "product_url": "https://www.fake.com/cat/subcat/456",
                        "business": 67.89
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    "Customer Name 2": { ... },
    ...
}
```

where customer name must be whatever is in the tsv file value. And the url is constructed using the category, sub category and product id field. The business value is the value of sales. I am not sure how to do this in Javascript. This is what I have so far, but I am getting `[]` as an output:

```
function tsvJSON(tsv){

    var lines=tsv.split("\n");

    var result = [];

    var headers=lines[0].split("\t");

    for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

        var obj = {};
        var currentline=lines[i].split("\t");

        for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
            obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }

        result.push(obj);

    }

    //return result; //JavaScript object
    return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
  }
console.log(tsvJSON("./sampledata.tsv"));
```

Comment: Can you better format the TSV you pasted so that we can read it? You should be able to with the code formatting you used for the JSON

Comment: Does that look better?

Comment: Much better. I think @odinn has the answer below though.

Answer (score 1):

so first of all, the problem is that you are not loading the file, you are just passing a file name and since you start the first loop with `i=1` it will not go into it because there is only one line, which is the filename... Try doing something like:

```
function tsvJSON(tsv) {
  const lines = tsv.split("\n");
  const result = [];
  const headers = lines[0].split("\t");

  for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const obj = {};
    const currentline = lines[i].split("\t");

    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
    }

    result.push(obj);
  }

  return result;
}

const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const tsvFileData = readFileSync('./sampledata.tsv');
const jsonRes = tsvJSON(tsvFileData.toString());

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonRes));
```

This should work for you, as you can see I read the file first and the pass it to your function... Sorry I had to change var to const and let... My personal bug in head :)

Comment: Hello @Odinn, how would you output the json in the format required? Like instead of having a json object be subcategory and category, instead would output product url which is "someurl/subcategory+category"? I was thinking of using maps or some if/else statement but I have never done that before

Comment: read about map or reduce in JS there are plenty examples of how to use that there is no magic way of doing what you need to do, you need to go over the data and create a new object with the required format and keep adding to it. Also would recommend reading on how objects work in JS and how to manipulate them. If this is homework u don't need to worry about it being performant as well i guess

Answer (score 1):

```js
const tsv2arr = (tsv) => {
  const [headers, ...rows] = tsv .trim () .split ('\n') .map (r => r .split ('\t'))
  return rows .reduce ((a, r) => [
    ... a, 
    Object .assign (... (r .map (
      (x, i, _, c = x.trim()) => ({[headers [i].trim()]: isNaN(c) ? c : Number(c)})
    )))
  ], [])
}

const tsv = `
Row ID O ID     O Date Ship Date Ship Type Customer ID Customer Name Seg       Country         City     State    Zip Code Region Product ID Category Sub-Category Product Name                     Sales Quantity Discount Profit
1 PA-152156 11/9/20 01/19/16 Second Class CG-125   Clay bute Consumer United States Henderson Kentucky 42420    South FUR-BO-10001798 Furniture Bookcases Bush, Somerset Collection Bookcase? 261.96 2         0         41.9136
2 ST-621973 8/9/20 02/10/16 First Class XY-139   Foobar Inc Consumer United States Madison  Wisconsin 53702    Midwest FUR-SO-10003869 Furniture Sofas    Tyler, Some Random Sofa Name     963.85 1         0         265.89
3 MQ-169437 12/7/20 03/15/16 Second Class CG-125   Clay bute Consumer United States Henderson Kentucky 42420    South FUR-DE-10005309 Furniture Desk     Adams, Some Random Desks Name?   654.13 1         0         143.28
`


console .log (
  tsv2arr (tsv)
)
```